# Master display setting for Windows C# forms

Tags: c#, css, .net, forms

I am developing an application using windows C# forms, .Net 3.5
The application contains different forms to receive user input, display report, etc.

While developing those forms, I have to swtich between forms to ensure that their outlook (e.g. font size, form size) are consistency. I do it by editing the form properties.

My question, is it possible to have a master style sheet (like CSS) to control the properties of all forms? Or how to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way like CSS, but you can write a method that enumerates all controls on a form and style them

```
StyleIt<Label>(this, lbl => { lbl.ForeColor = Color.Red; });
```

---

```
void StyleIt<T>(Form f, Action<T> action)
{
    Func<Control, IEnumerable<Control>> allControls = null;
    allControls = root => new Control[] { root }
                          .Concat(root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                                               .SelectMany(c => allControls(c)));

    allControls(f).OfType<T>().ToList()
                  .ForEach(tb => action(tb));
}
```